# I want to insert data to my database but it does not work

Tags: php, mysql, post, pdo

everything seems fine and should work but it does not I get the variables they are like should be so I dont know why it does not insert data in my database 
the code:

```
  <?php

date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Vilnius"); 


if(isset($_POST['priduot'])){

$data =date("Y.m.d"); 

$vardas=$_POST[vardas];

$pavarde=$_POST[pavarde];

 $uzsakymas=$_POST[uzsakymas];

$kiekis =$_POST[kiekis];

$busena=$_POST[busena];

$dbhost = "mysql.hostinger.lt";

$dbname = "u878197685_vehub";

$dbusername = "u878197685_ryzuh";

$dbpassword = "svetaineairida";

$lentele  = "Uzsakymai";


 //the part that does not work

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbusername,$dbpassword);

$statement = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `$lentele ` ( `Vardas`, `Pavarde`, `Uzsakymas`, `Kiekis`, `Uzsakymobusena`, `UzsakymoData`) 

  VALUES (:Vardas, :Pavarde, :Uzsakymas, :Kiekis, :Uzsakymobusena, :UzsakymoData)");

$statement->execute(array(

 "Vardas" => $vardas,

    "Pavarde" => $pavarde,

    "Uzsakymas" => $uzsakymas,

    "Kiekis" => $kiekis,

"Uzsakymobusena" => $busena,

"UzsakymoData" => $data
//the part that does not work

));
}

 ?>
```

Comment: maybe now change your password

Comment: try to add `$conn->error` and check exact error what is ocuring. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Reason being, your POST arrays require quotes.

```
$vardas=$_POST['vardas'];
```

and do the same for the others.

Error reporting would have triggered notices, but you're not checking for them.

Sidenote:

Make sure your form does have a POST method `method = "post"` and that all your inputs hold the "name" attribute.

I.e.:

```
<input type="text" name="vardas">
```

etc.

Including the one for your conditional statement:

```
if(isset($_POST['priduot'])){...}
```

If the related input for it isn't named, then nothing in there will execute, even after making those changes.

Use an `else{ echo "No success"; }` with it. If it falls in that, then you have errors somewhere.

---

Error reporting:

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Also add `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, which may also catch other errors.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 0):

The below keys will all need to be enclosed in quotation marks, like this:

```
$vardas=$_POST['vardas'];
$pavarde=$_POST['pavarde'];
$uzsakymas=$_POST['uzsakymas'];
$kiekis =$_POST['kiekis'];
$busena=$_POST['busena'];
```

Comment: The lack of quotes around the mentioned indices trigger notices but that's all about them. PHP assumes the symbols are constants, cannot find them and use them as strings instead. The changes suggested by this answer, although correct, do not fix the problem (they just prevent the triggering of notices.)

Answer (score 0):

Actually that what "Fred -ii-" && d0ug7a5 says is true , but there is something in addition if you was not saw it yet
   `$lentele ` have to be `$lentele`.
Sometimes little typos like this may to lost a lot of your time :)